# Problems associated with $\mathcal{O}(\cdot)$

Tags: limits, definite-integrals

Let $f\in C^3[0,1]$. Let's define
$$
\Delta_n=\int_0^1 f(x) dx-\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right), \\
\Delta'_n=\int_0^1 f(x) dx-\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left( \dfrac{2k-1}{2n} \right).
$$
I have three problems to solve:

1. Prove that $\Delta_n=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac1n\right)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$,
2. Evaluate $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\Delta_n$,
3. Prove that $\Delta'_n=\mathcal{O}\left(\dfrac1{n^2}\right)$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**Hint** Use Taylor's Theorem.

**My attempts**

1. Using the definition which says that when $f(x)=\mathcal{O}(g(x))$ then there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such that
   $$
   |f(x)|\leq Mg(x) \ \ \forall_{x\geq x_0},
   $$
   we have to show that for certain $M$ we have
   $$
   \left|\Delta_n  \right|=\left| \int_0^1 f(x) dx-\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right)  \right|\leq M\cdot \frac1n \ \ \forall_{x\geq x_0}.
   $$
   How to find such $M$ and $x_0$?
2. $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n\Delta_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \left(  \int_0^1 f(x) dx-\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) \right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}n \left(  \dfrac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) -\dfrac1n\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f\left( \dfrac{k}{n} \right) \right) =0. $

Is it correct?

3. I haven't got any sensible ideas.

Comment: Have you drawn some pictures of some different functions to try to convince yourself that any of these are true? That may help you to work out a strategy.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't make the proof.